Referenced project may not disable emit
I'm working on a Vue3 app with TS (using VScode). Today, I saw that the intellisense wasn't working so I searched for the issue and it seemed to be that I didn't have this line in my tsconfig.json:
"include": ["./src/**/*"]
So I added this, but now I have this error, which I don't really understand :

the error message :
Referenced project may not disable emit
the line where it occurs :

  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    }
  ],

I tried to switch the noEmit key of tsconfig.app.json and tsconfig.node.json to false and it doesn't raise the error anymore, but I don't really understand the problem and I didn't saw anybody tell to put the value to false in order to solve the problem.
Anyway, I would be very glad if somebody could explain me what the problem actually is and if my fix is correct.

Intellisense where? The problems with TS and Vue SFC you observe in an IDE are specific to it, unless proven otherwise. Because the support of non-standard formats depends on particular implementation of a tool. "include" entry in your setup belongs to tsconfig.app.json, not tsconfig.json. If an IDE is unable to support "references" correctly, this is IDE problem

include does exist in my tsconfig.app.json (with the good configuration), but my IDE does not notify me of typescript issues if I don't put it in tsconfig.json. You may be right, it could be a problem with my IDE, but frankly I don't really know where to look out for help related to that

Be aware of TS version that VSC uses, it's in status line and can be switched. Could possibly be solved when the version is changed. Make sure it's reproducible with the latest IDE version from scratch and latest global TS installation, try VSC portable to not destroy your current installation. If it's possible to not involve Vue and Volar to reproduce it, this would keep it simpler.

In the end you'd be able to either narrow down the issue to a specific thing you use or have a bug in VSC itself that can be reported in VSC repo. Most likely the former, because VSC doesn't have problems with this afaik. Check in the issues if there are already some regarding "references" keyword (aka composite config)
